# ALSA Api: How to play two wave files simultaneously?

Tags: c, linux, audio, alsa

What is the required API configuration/call for playing two independent wavefiles overlapped ?
I tried to do so , I am getting resource busy error. Some pointers to solve the problem will be very helpful.

Following is the error message from `snd_pcm_prepare()` of the second wavefile

```
"Device or resource busy"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ALSA does not provide a mixer. If you need to play multiple audio streams at the same time, you need to mix them together on your own.

The easiest way this can be accomplished is by decoding the WAV files to `float` samples, add them, and clip them when converting them back to integer samples.

Alternatively, you can try to open the *default* audio device (and *not* a hardware device like "hw:0") multiple times, once for each stream you wish to play, and hope that the dmix ALSA plugin is loaded and will provide the mixing functionality.

Comment: what about the mixer utility of alsa? Can I use it to mix audio ?

Comment: @LunarMushrooms I was talking about mixing multiple audio streams together, not the mixer control utility for managing volume levels.

Answer (score 24):

You can configure ALSA's `dmix` plugin to allow multiple applications to share input/output devices.

An example configuration to do this is below:

```
pcm.dmixed {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    ipc_key_add_uid 0
    slave.pcm "hw:0,0"
}
pcm.dsnooped {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 1025
    slave.pcm "hw:0,0"
}

pcm.duplex {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "dmixed"
    capture.pcm "dsnooped"
}

# Instruct ALSA to use pcm.duplex as the default device
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "duplex"
}
ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}
```

This does the following:

- creates a new device using the `dmix` plugin, which allows multiple apps to share the output stream
- creates another using `dsnoop` which does the same thing for the input stream
- merges these into a new `duplex` device that will support input and output using the `asym` plugin
- tell ALSA to use the new `duplex` device as the default device
- tell ALSA to use `hw:0` to control the default device (alsamixer and so on)

Stick this in either `~/.asoundrc` or `/etc/asound.conf` and you should be good to go.

For more information see http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc#Software_mixing.

Comment: Genius!!!! Jonny, you are the HERO, yes you are. Thanks a lot no millions. Great job, this is great, i hate PulseAudio, shame on them its 2013 and PA crash, made us handycap. Where Alsa is the best forever and only i had this multi output issue with your script, its 500% working. Thank you, keep it up best answers.

Answer (score 2):

As ALSA provides a mixer device by default (dmix), you can simply use aplay, like so :

```
aplay song1.wav &
aplay -Dplug:dmix song2.wav
```

If your audio files are the same rate and format, then you don't need to use plug. It becomes :

```
aplay song1.wav &
aplay -Ddmix song2.wav
```

If however you want to program this method, there are some C++ audio programming [tutorials here](http://forum.audioinjector.net/viewtopic.php@f=10&t=2982.html). These tutorials show you how to load audio files and operate different audio subsystems, such as jackd and ALSA.

In [this example](https://github.com/flatmax/gtkiostream/blob/master/test/ALSAPlaybackTest.C) it demonstrates playback of one audio file using ALSA. It can be modified by opening a second audio file like so :

```
Sox<short int> sox2;
res=sox2.openRead(argv[2]);
if (res<0 && res!=SOX_READ_MAXSCALE_ERROR)
  return SoxDebug().evaluateError(res);
```

Then modify [the while loop](https://github.com/flatmax/gtkiostream/blob/master/test/ALSAPlaybackTest.C#L107-L119) like so :

```
  Eigen::Array<int, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> buffer, buffer2;
  size_t totalWritten=0;
  while (sox.read(buffer, pSize)>=0 && sox2.read(buffer2, pSize)>=0){
    if (buffer.rows()==0 || buffer.rows()==0) // end of the file.
      break;
    // as the original files were opened as short int, summing will not overload the int buffer.
    buffer+=buffer2; // sum the two waveforms together
    playBack<<buffer; // play the audio data
    totalWritten+=buffer.rows();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this configuration also

```
   pcm.dmix_stream
   {
       type dmix
        ipc_key 321456 
        ipc_key_add_uid true
        slave.pcm "hw:0,0"
   }


   pcm.mix_stream
   {
      type plug
      slave.pcm dmix_stream
   }
```

Update it in ~/.asoundrc or /etc/asound.conf

You can use command

For wav file

aplay -D mix_stream "filename"

For raw or pcmfile

aplay -D mix_stream -c "channels" -r "rate" -f "format" "filename"

Enter the value for channels, rate, format and filename as per your audio file

Answer (score 0):

following is a very simplified multi-thread playback solution (assuming both files are the same sample format, same channel number and same frequency):

1. starting buffer based thread per each file decoding (have to make this code 2 times - for `file1` and for `file2`):

   ```
   import wave
   import threading

   periodsize = 160
   f = wave.open(file1Wave, 'rb')
   file1Alive = True
   file1Thread = threading.Thread(target=_playFile1)
   file1Thread.daemon = True
   file1Thread.start()
   ```
2. file decoding thread itself (also has to be defined twice - for `file1` and for `file2`) :

   ```
   def _playFile1():
       # Read data from RIFF
       while file1Alive:
           if file1dataReady:
               time.sleep(.001)
           else:
               data1 = f.readframes(periodsize)
               if not data1:
                   file1Alive = False
                   f.close()
               else:
                   file1dataReady == True
   ```
3. starting merging thread (aka `funnel`) to merge file decodings

   ```
   import alsaaudio
   import threading

   sink = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_PLAYBACK, device="hw:CARD=default")
   sinkformat = 2
   funnelalive = True
   funnelThread = threading.Thread(target=self._funnelLoop)
   funnelThread.daemon = True
   funnelThread.start()
   ```
4. merge and play (aka `funnel`) thread

   ```
   def _funnelLoop():
       # Reading all Inputs
       while funnelalive:
           # if nothing to play - time to selfdestruct
           if not file1Alive and not file2Alive:
               funnelalive = False
               sink.close()
           else:
               if file1dataReady and file2dataReady: 
                   # merging data from others but first
                   datamerged = audioop.add(data2, data2, sinkformat)
                   file1dataReady = False
                   file2dataReady = False
                   sink.write(datamerged)
                   time.sleep(.001)
   ```