# Python speech recognition for Raspberry Pi 3 B parallel access

Tags: speech-recognition, raspberry-pi3, alsa, pyaudio

I am making voice recognition robot using raspberry pi, So I use usb sound card for microphone input. So I set the default sound input output on raspberry pi by changing  /etc/asound.conf file to:

```
pcm.!default {
        type hw card 1
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw card 1
}
```

So I use the python SpeechRecognition library and requesting microphone by bellow code:

```
m = sr.Microphone(device_index = 2, sample_rate =44100, chunk_size =512)
```

The problem is, It works well at the first call. but then I used the same microphone call again, it gives me bellow error message:

```
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1514
Expression 'ValidateParameters( inputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_In )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2818
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what is going wrong???
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ALSA Api: How to play two wave files simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398573/alsa-api-how-to-play-two-wave-files-simultaneously)

Comment: You can configure alsa properly to allow parallel access. But overall it is better to open microphone once and avoid opening microphone multiple times.